# Convert String to corresponding Forms.Keys value?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

I am looking for a way to convert the value of a `string` to the equivalent `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` item. Then this value will be used with `PressKey` to simulate the corresponding Key. I tried using the `KeyConverter` like this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    public static void PressKey(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, bool up)
        {
            const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
            const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
            if (up)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
            }
            else
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
            }
        }

    KeyConverter kc = new KeyConverter();
    PressKey((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)kc.ConvertFromString(string), false);
```

What I need is a `string` like `"Enter"` to be converted to `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter`. But `KeyConverter` is not returning anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: "Key" is too broad a term. Be careful with diction/tags :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to convert a string into the corresponding enumeration value:

```
public static Keys ConvertFromString(string keystr) {
    return (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), keystr);
}
```

Note that `Enum.Parse` will throw an `ArgumentException` if the key string is not in the enumeration. If you don't want that, use `Enum.TryParse` instead, which returns a bool indicating if the conversion was successful.

Comment: Errors are already handled in my application and this works! Thanks :D

Comment: Note that `Enum.TryParse` was only added in .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 5):

`System.Windows.Forms.Keys` is an enum, so you can use  [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Keys key;
Enum.TryParse("Enter", out key);
```

It was introduced with .NET framework 4.0 and it's a lot more readable than `Enum.Parse` because the type parameter is inferred automatically.

You can check the boolean return value to see if the conversion succeeded, eliminating the need to catch an exception for undefined enum values.

Comment: Awesome, did not realize they'd added this in .NET 4.