# ShortcutKey from string

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to provider user with option to set [`ToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys.aspx) via configuration file, so I've figured out that I need somehow transform `string` to [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx).

I've [already found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449484/convert-string-to-corresponding-forms-keys-value) how to do that for simple values using [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx), but it won't recognize formats like:

- `Ctrl+i` (with space at the end)
- `i`
- `Ctrl+Alt+Esc`

**Q:** Is there any *standardized* way of parsing stings (`Ctrl+i`) to `Keys`?

*I'd like to avoid writing my own function that will split text into pieces and then handle each case/special string separately.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The string you see in the Properties window for the ShortcutKeys property is generated by a TypeConverter.  You can use that type converter in your own code as well.  Like this:

```
    var txt = "Ctrl+I";
    var cvt = new KeysConverter();
    var key = (Keys)cvt.ConvertFrom(txt);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(key == (Keys.Control | Keys.I));
```

Do beware that `I` or `Ctrl+Alt+Escape` are not valid short-cut keys.  KeysConverter will not complain, you'll get the exception when you assign the ShortCutKeys property.  Wrap both with try/except to catch invalid config data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can separate the values with a `,` - however your string would still need massaged because `Ctrl` and `Esc` are not valid `Keys` values. They still need to be valid values. So consider the following code:

```
var keys = "Ctrl+Alt+Esc";
keys = keys.Replace("+", ",").Replace("Ctrl", "Control").Replace("Esc", "Escape");
var k = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), keys);
```

Further, here is the code in the `Enum` class that's going to pick that up:

```
string[] array = value.Split(Enum.enumSeperatorCharArray);
ulong[] array2;
string[] array3;
Enum.GetCachedValuesAndNames(runtimeType, out array2, out array3, true, true);
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = array[i].Trim();
    bool flag = false;
    int j = 0;
    while (j < array3.Length)
    {
        if (ignoreCase)
        {
            if (string.Compare(array3[j], array[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                goto IL_152;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (array3[j].Equals(array[i]))
            {
                goto IL_152;
            }
        }
        j++;
        continue;
        IL_152:
        ulong num2 = array2[j];
        num |= num2;
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
    if (!flag)
    {
        parseResult.SetFailure(Enum.ParseFailureKind.ArgumentWithParameter, "Arg_EnumValueNotFound", value);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The value of `enumSeperatorCharArray` is:

```
private static readonly char[] enumSeperatorCharArray = new char[]
{
    ','
};
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing my own parser (although I'd end up with something like this), spiting on `+,-` and then trimming whitespaces, using `ToUpper()` for single characters and `ToLower()` and mapping with longer names, but from my experience you'll always forgot something in sources like this.

Comment: @Vyktor, you're not writing your own parser. But you have to get the string into a state in which the `Enum` class can actually `Parse` the string. How would you expect it to parse `Ctrl`? Does that miraculously turn into `Control`? I mean you're going to have to massage it some, but I've got it to where you can separate with the `,` (because it's built in), and then just massage the abbreviations.