# How to convert string to Keys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, key, typeconverter

Trying to implement a combination of key pressing for my program
currently can detect the required key pressed (in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076051/how-to-use-keypressevent-in-correct-way/19076076#19076076) described how) but only predefined in code, but I want to store the setting in a config file then read it and use it if pressed.

Now can store it, and read as string - currently try to convert read string to `Keys`, using the following code:

Storing in config file:

```
<add key="open" value="ControlKey,N"
<add key="close" value="ControlKey,Q" />
<add key="clear" value="ControlKey,D" />
<add key="settings" value="ControlKey,S" />
<add key="colorKey" value="ControlKey,K" />
<add key="fontKey" value="ShiftKey,T" />
<add key="defaultKey" value="ControlKey,P" />
```

and using it

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Keys));
        string[] keyValueTemp;

        keyValueTemp = cm.GetValueString("open").ToString().Split(',');
        string key1 = keyValueTemp[0];
        string key2 = keyValueTemp[1];

        Keys keys1 = (Keys)converter.ConvertFromString(key1);
        Keys keys2 = (Keys)converter.ConvertFromString(key2);

        if (ModifierKeys == keys1 && e.KeyCode == keys2)
        {
            string keyPressed = e.KeyCode.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(keyPressed);
        }
    }
```

But, has next result -

[image]
So - as you see - this converts ControlKey to Shiftkey, also try to use code  `if (ModifierKeys.ToString() == keyValueTemp[0] && e.KeyCode.ToString() == keyValueTemp[1])`, but it's not work too.

if I use this code

```
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.N)
        {
            string keyPressed = e.KeyCode.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(keyPressed);
        }
```

all works

Q: how can I convert string to Keys and compare it with keyPressed events?

EDIT

So found my mistake

```
Keys key = (Keys)converter.ConvertFromString(keyValueTemp[0]);
Keys key2 = (Keys)converter.ConvertFromString(keyValueTemp[1]);
if (e.Modifiers == key && e.KeyCode == key2)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
   }
```

forget to add `e` - from the event handler

another way - as written by **AccessDenied**

```
 Keys key = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), keyValueTemp[0], true);
```

Comment: Check this answer may be it would be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449484/convert-string-to-corresponding-forms-keys-value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Key comparision is done with enumerations, So what you have to do is a `String to Enum` conversion.

```
if (e.Modifiers == (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "keys1", true)
    && e.KeyCode == (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "keys2", true))
{
    string keyPressed = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(keyPressed);
}
```

Comment: yep - it's work perfect, thanks, also found another solution - see EDIT

Answer (score 11):

```
Keys key;
Enum.TryParse("Enter", out key);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest you not to store keys in config as "ControlKey,N", rather store its value.

```
 Keys openKey = Keys.ControlKey | Keys.N;
 int value = (int)openKey;//95
```

It integer representation is `95`, So store in app.config as

```
<add key="open" value="95">//ControlKey|N

Keys open = (Keys)int.Parse(cm.GetValueString("open").ToString());
```

Here open will be `Keys.ControlKey | Keys.N`

Then you can compare easily against `e.KeyData`

```
if(e.KeyData == open)
{
    //Control + N pressed
}
```

Comment: but what wrong if i store my key in string like `ControlKey,N` ?

Comment: Don't you think you're doing additional work by splititing it up with comma into two entries, parsing it to two `Keys` and checking with `modifier` and `KeyCode`. Isn't it better to store the value and compare against `e.KeyData`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it the following way.
In app.config file I have the following

```
<add key="KeyboardShortcut" value="Control+M" />
```

and to use it in my code-file

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Keys ShortCutKeys
{
    get
    {
        string keyboardShortcut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyboardShortcut"];
        System.Windows.Forms.Keys retval = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyboardShortcut))
        {
            try
            {
                 System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter kc = new System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter();
                 retval = (System.Windows.Forms.Keys)kc.ConvertFromInvariantString(keyboardShortcut);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info(ex.ToString());           
            }
       }
       return retval;
    }
}
```

And to detect if the key was pressed

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    try
    {           
        if (this.ShortCutKeys != Keys.None && (keyData & this.ShortCutKey) == this.ShortCutKey)
        {
            this.Execute_Plugin();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of Muhammad Umar answer.

For version 3.5  of .NET or before you can do

```
Keys key = Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "Enter");
```

Be carefull to catch exceptions.